# download error Diabetic Retinopathy dataset from Kaggle

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, kaggle

I was starting new project of Diabetic retinopathy but now it shows error in dataset download. Though it gets downloaded, unzipping results error. This consist of 5 training dataset consisting more than 8 GB each. I am in huge trouble. How can i solve this ?
Here is the download link of dataset: 
https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection/data

Comment: Can you share any insights on what you tried that resulted in an error? Also, if the download is not directly performed in Python, I would suggest altering the tags slightly, to better represent your actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah ! I found its solution. Unzipping dataset using winRAR resulted aforementioned problem. Using 7zip for extracting is the solution. My friend found this solution. 
Thanks